# Optimize app for all devices iOS

Tags: ios, optimization, screen-size

How can I optimise my application for all devices using storyboard and be able to see how the constraints apply to each device.

Comment: This questions is edited, so the answer for this question is the following. Click on the assistant editor then choose Preview instead of Manual. Then add all the devices by clicking on the ( + ) to see how the content appears on each view. Now you can work with the constraints and see how they apply on each screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. Use one storyboard (or xib per class) and use auto layout.

Comment: Don't forget [*size classes*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) and the old but reliable *springs and struts*.